# Match paragraph and replace with new paragraph using sed/awk/grep

Tags: xml, bash, shell, awk, sed

I want to do match multiple continuous lines in a file and then replace it with new multiple continuous lines. For example:

Pattern:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

to be replaced with :

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
        connectionTimeout="20000"
         acceptCount="450" maxConnections="10000"
           redirectPort="8443" server=" " />
```

Even though here few keywords are common in both the paragraph but just consider them different.

I tried with following but could not get success:

```
sed -i 's/<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP\/1.1" \nconnectionTimeout="20000" \nredirectPort="8443" \/>/<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP\/1.1" \nconnectionTimeout="20000" \nacceptCount="450" maxConnections="10000" \nredirectPort="8443" server=" " \/>/g' server.xml
```

How can i achieve above.

Thanks.

Comment: That's not a paragraph, it's an XML tag. Use tools that understand XML and are intended to manipulate it.

Comment: Thanks Shawn for your prompt reply. But i want to do it using sed or awk or grep. Can we do this without any XML tool.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: Wanting to use things like sed to work with XML is like using a hammer to drive a screw. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks Cyrus. I cant use such tools. I want to do this processing using bash/shell script.

Comment: If you want to use tools that most professionals would consider totally unsuited to the task, at least explain why you want to do so. Remember, we see lots of posts every day from people wanting to know how to cope with invalid XML, which is the inevitable result of people generating XML using the wrong tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option `-z` of sed allows to replace multiline block easily :

```
sed -E -z 's!(<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"\
\s+connectionTimeout="20000"\
\s+)(redirectPort="8443")!\1acceptCount="450" maxConnections="10000"\
           \2 server=" "!'   inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `sed` or `awk` although a tool made for the job may be better.

```
sed -E '/[a-zA-Z]*."20000"/ {N;s|[a-z]*"8443".*|acceptCount="450" maxConnections="10000"\n\t\tredirectPort="8443" server=" " />|}'
```

```
awk 'NR==3{$0="\t\tacceptCount=\"450\" maxConnections=\"10000\"\n\t\tredirectPort=\"8443\" server=\" \"/>"}1'
```